# Yum- disable database update on package install

Tags: yum, fedora-15

I'm using Fedora 15 and every time I try to install something with yum, yum tries to update the repository database.

For most people this would be great and handy, but I'm stuck behind super slow internet (well, kinda slow, something like 1 Mbps), and the update takes a minute or so.  The database isn't large (a little over 2 mb for all of my repositories), but it adds up.

**What is the best way to disable this automatic database update?** I'm used to Ubuntu and apt where I have to manually tell apt to update the databases. I suppose I could install apt for Fedora, but I was wondering if there was a config setting somewhere that I could change.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Passing `-C` to yum will tell it to only use the metadata in the current cache. Note that this will cause the operation to fail if it needs metadata that is not currently in the cache, or if the metadata from the various repositories are not in sync.

Comment: Can that be set in a config file somewhere? Passing -C every time may get tedious.  I want to tell yum when to update the metadata.

Comment: Unfortunately no. You will need to create an alias for it.

Comment: How about a "fast yum" alias: `alias yumin='yum -C --noplugins'`

Answer (score 4):

"... Can that be set in a config file somewhere? Passing -C every time may get tedious. ..."

Update YUM config file and set `metadata_expire` variable to a higher value (default is 90 mins.) You can then use `yum makecache` command to manually update the metadata as and when required.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer from : https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/212278/56487

## Temporary Solution:

Use `-C` flag:

```
sudo yum install foobar -C
```

## Permanent solution:

Use the `metadata_expire` flag in your **yum.conf** to control this.

Edit `/etc/yum.conf` and set

```
metadata_expire=15d
```

You can use *d, h or m* to configure the time in *days, hours, or minutes*.

Bonus: here is the documentation:

> metadata_expire is Time (in seconds) after which the metadata will expire. So that if the current metadata downloaded is less than  this
>                 many  seconds  old then yum will not update the metadata against the repository.  If you find that yum is not downloading information
>                 on updates as often as you would like lower the value of this option. You can also change from the default of using seconds to  using
>                 days,  hours  or  minutes  by appending a d, h or m respectively.  The default is 6 hours, to compliment yum-updatesd running once an
>                 hour.  It's also possible to use the word "never", meaning that the metadata will never expire. Note that when using a metalink  file
>                 the  metalink  must  always be newer than the metadata for the repository, due to the validation, so this timeout also applies to the
>                 metalink file.  Also note that "never" does not override "yum clean expire-cache"